# Eisbock chunk thawed

Tags: beer, frozen

It seemed a waste not to bottle my previously frozen ice chunk left over from an Eisbock recipe. It had all the smell and flavor and was a bit darker. Has anyone ever bottled their ice from icebock? Did it explode?

Comment: Wouldn't it be mostly free of alcohol? Isn't that the point of ice distillation?

Comment: If you didn't thaw it, you could shave it and make Sno-cones!  I've made Guinness sorbet a few times - add sugar to Guinness and throw it in an ice-cream maker.  Delicious!

Answer (score 2):

The freezing point of the ethanol in your eisbock is much lower than water, thus, your chunk is, sadly, just a big ice cube.

Answer (score 1):

The ice is water with little, if any, alcohol to it.  There's really no reason to bottle it.